# Objects are not valid as a React child problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m having problems when I try to map a json into my react component and I don t know by..

this is the structure:

```
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "fares": [
        {
          "fareRef": "1",
          "prices": {
            "afterTax": 100
          }
        }
      ],
      "international": false,
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "fares": [
        {
          "fareRef": "1",
          "prices": {
            "afterTax": 200
          }
        }
      ],
      "international": false,
    },

  ]
}
```

and inside my component I m doing this:

```
 cards.map(element => (
  <p>{element.id}</p> // works!
  <p>{element.fares.map(element => element.prices)}</p> // dosen 't work..
))
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What do you want React to do with your `{ "afterTax": 200 }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is the desired behaviour, but right now, you are trying to render an object (`element.prices`) as part of the `<p>` element. Assuming you are trying to display the `afterTax` values, you should be referencing the `afterTax` property within `prices`.

```
cards.map(element => (
  <p>{element.id}</p> // works!
  <p>{element.fares.map(element => element.prices.afterTax)}</p>
))
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `element.fares.prices` in your 2nd map call comes out to be:

```
"prices": {
            "afterTax": 100
          }
```

You're rendering an object, which is not allowed. Try `element.fares.prices.afterTax`.

```
cards.map(card => (
  <p>{card.id}</p> // works!
  <p>{card.fares.map(fare => fare.prices.afterTax)}</p> // dosen 't work..
))
```

Comment: Which element are you replacing? The second one, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
cards.map(card => (
  <p>{card.id}</p>
  <p>{card.fares.map(fare => fare.prices)}</p>
))
```

In general, you should avoid using generic variable names like `element` to label the items of an iterable to avoid name clashes like this.

Also, did you mean to render an object? Because `fare.prices` is an object. Did you mean to render `fare.prices.afterTax` instead? If that's the case, then it should be:

```
cards.map(card => (
  <p>{card.id}</p>
  <p>{card.fares.map(fare => fare.prices.afterTax)}</p>
))
```

Comment: Also, what are you trying to render exactly? The afterTax value for each price? Or the price object itself?

Comment: The afterTaxValue for each price. Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {afterTax}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are creating a new array of objects from element.fares that looks like `[ { afterTax: 100 }, { afterTax: 200 }]`. React can't render those objects so it spits out that error. If you want to see the fares, try something like:

```
cards.map(element => (
  <p>{element.id}</p>
  <p>{element.fares.map(element => element.prices.afterTax)}</p>
))
```

Obviously you'll have to format it because this will literally result in 100200 but gives you an idea of what's wrong.